# how to convert lists of list to particular dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, list

here is my list , i want to convert it into a Dataframe

```
list =[["32:31",1,56],
      ["25:31",2,78],
      ["08:31",3,3],
      ["28:41",4,98]]
```

can we convert this list to Dataframe like -:
(i want to fetch third element only)

```
   a
  56
  78
   3
  98
```

i tried `df = pd.DataFrame(list)` with some condition but it didn't work out

please help me

thanks

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame([e[2] for e in list])`? Also do not use list as variable name, it shadows the built-in name list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use variable `list`, because python code word.

Use `DataFrame` contructor with list comprehension for get 3. value by indexing `[2]` (python count from `0`):

```
L =[["32:31",1,56],
    ["25:31",2,78],
    ["08:31",3,3],
    ["28:41",4,98]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[x[2] for x in L]})
print (df)
    a
0  56
1  78
2   3
3  98
```

Comment: @AmitGupta - yes, it was answered after me... check times.

Comment: hey, this is just curiosity question, is this possible without iteration? because i have very huge amount of data(means list size is too large)

Comment: Yes, use `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list(zip(*L))[2]})`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

_list =[["32:31",1,56],
      ["25:31",2,78],
      ["08:31",3,3],
      ["28:41",4,98]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[elem[2] for elem in _list]})    
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
    a
0  56
1  78
2   3
3  98
```